# Creating words with "-able" suffix

Tags: adjectives, orthography, suffixes, able-eable

What are general rules of thumb for creating adjectives with *-able*? I wanted to denote an object as having an ability to be tiled, but "tileable" and "tilable" both yielded as incorrect words by spell check and standard English dictionary used by Mac OS X dictionary widget. Is "tileable" or "tilable" a correct word/form for denoting an object having an ability to be tiled?

Comment: [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/tileable) gives 'tileable' (the mathematical sense has been around for many years). Use better dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I see it, you've got two choices here if the word doesn't already have an acceptable -able suffix counterpart. Either

1. Reword the sentence so you don't need to use the -able suffix
2. Hyphenate it. E.g. tile-able.

Although, Googling it, 'tileable' seems to be pretty widely used anyway.

Comment: I am a developer so I wanted to use this word in a camel cased constant. Something like TileableObjectType in constants is more often used than ObjectThatCanBeTiled.

Comment: TileableObjectType should be fine, then, IMO! That or TileMeBabyPlease.

Answer (score 11):

As the NOAD reports, *-able* is a suffix forming adjectives meaning:

- able to be: *calculable*.
- due to be: *payable*.
- subject to: *taxable*.
- relevant to or in accordance with: *fashionable*.
- having the quality to: *suitable*, *comfortable*.

The meaning of *tile-able* would be *to be able to be tiled*.
The spelling checker I am using reports the word as wrong, but it suggests also *tile-able*.
As reported in *Common Sense* (ISBN 13: 978-0-312-34255-5; ISBN 10: 0-312-34255-1), a book about punctuation marks, a hyphen is used *in words consisting of a prefix and a root, if not using one will cause to run together either two vowels or a small letter and a capital*.

- anti-inflammatory
- un-American
- extra-alkaline
- pre-Christian

Comment: So the dash is mandatory?

Comment: I added that part to the answer, as that should be explained.

Comment: So it's write-able?

Comment: @AndreKR It's _writable_.

Comment: Just *writeable*, esp., if it's a disc (disk).

Comment: @Kris _Writeable_ is not a word you find in the dictionary. _Writable_ means "able to be written or set down in writing; suitable for writing with" and can be used for disks too.

Comment: *Writeable* is used all the time by Microsoft (e.g., msdn) among others. A Google search shows ~15 million results for *writable* vs. ~18.5M for *writeable*.

Comment: @Kris Right, but the fact Microsoft uses _writeable_ doesn't mean that is the word to use, and _writable_ is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

*The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style* by Bryan A. Garner has a helpful list under **‑able**, including the choice between *‑able* and *‑ible*, attaching *‑able* to nouns, to intransitive verbs, converting *‑ate* verbs into *‑able* adjectives, and even on dropping or retaining the medial *‑e‑*.

A quick reference table is on the [Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195135084.001.0001/acref-9780195135084-e-7?rskey=oiZhnc&result=8&q=). You can try the Google Books source at [ODAUS p4](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the detailed treatment.

*Survey of English Spelling* by Edward Carney explains some etymological (source language) factors of the “[spelling problem](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=XXPgVnLh5AoC&pg=PA424&lpg=PA424&dq=%22Choice%20of%20-able%20or%20-ible%22&source=bl&ots=O_iYit9Ish&sig=pXqtTcVUjRH7EPef6d-OnTbm1R8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mYG4UMDLKMbRrQemx4DABQ&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Choice%20of%20-able%20or%20-ible%22&f=false)”.