# Is "pronunciable" or "pronounceable" more correct, considering etymology?

Tags: etymology, orthography

The former seems more natural to me, and is personally what I've used, but the latter is easier to pronounce.

Comment: Why does pronounciable look more natural to you?

Comment: Actually the best orthography for the word is **pronunceabill** because it is both the earliest attested form and the most aesthetically cool :p

Comment: The OED entry gives "rare" for "pronunciable" (one appearance every 100 million words...). I would estimate that 97.4% of the English speaking world would immediately think it was a typo or simply wrong. (PS: "correct" is an ungradeable adjective.)

Comment: Etymology has ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to tell you about which of the possible forms a word might have are actually in use in a particular language at a particular time. (I don't do "correct" because I'm not interested in fashion, even in the part of fashion which applies to speech, and some people call "grammar". )

Comment: I can't find **pronunciable** in a dictionary. Did you find it?

Answer (score 2):

*Pronunciable* is incorrect. The correct adjective for ‘something that can be pronounced’ is **pronounceable**. Adjectives that end with the suffix *-able* are mostly formed from (transitive) verbs. In this case, the verb is ‘pronounce’:

- pronounce (verb) + able → pronounceable
- manage + able → manageable
- update + able → updateable (updatable)
- enjoy + able → enjoyable

Also note that you [cannot remove the ***e***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/533789/365490) from ‘pronounc**e**able’ because if you do, it will turn the /s/ of ‘pronounce’ to a /k/ (**pronouncable*).