# Are both "tradable" and "tradeable" correct?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I was wondering whether "tradeable" is the British English version of the American word "tradable"?

Given that the word "trade" ends with an "e", I compare it to the word "love" which I see more often as "lovable".

Comment: Note that evidence from Google Books suggests that *tradable* is the more commonly used  form, both in BrE and AmE. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tradeable%2Ctradable&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctradeable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctradable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Following on from @Decapitated Soul's comment:  'Bridgeable' is far more common than 'bridgable' (Google Ngrams), though the fact that 'bridgable' exists shows that some don't consider it necessary to include the 'e' for the informing of pronunciation. // But this question is crying out for readily available data.  Dictionaries often mention 'AmE' vs 'BrE' spelling preferences, and Ngram searches may be suitably refined. _And wouldn't the lexeme have first been used among Brits? It would then be a 'British word', however spelled._

Comment: There are no strong rules dictating one form or the other.  And good old Noah Webster threw things into a jumble by moving "e" around in many words.  Best you can do is pick the one that is most idiomatic in your dialect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's British/ American distinction. *Tradeable* and *tradable* are the same word having the same meaning.

The suffix *-able* is often added to verbs (and sometimes nouns) to make adjectives. When the base word ends with a silent *e* and the suffix *-able* is appended, then the *e* is often removed only if its removal doesn't change the pronunciation of the preceding consonant in the base word:

- trade + able → trad**ea**ble or trad**a**ble
- update + able → updat**ea**ble or updat**a**ble
- love + able → lov**ea**ble or lov**a**ble

However, when the base word ends in *-ge* or *-ce*, the *e* is kept:

- notice + able → notic**ea**ble **not** *notic**a**ble
- manage + able → manag**ea**ble **not** *manag**a**ble

in the above words, the *e* is kept because its removal turns /s/ and /d͡ʒ/ to /k/ and /g/, respectively.

In all of the OP's examples, the removal of the *e* doesn't change the pronunciation, so both forms are correct and acceptable. Which one to use is a matter of personal preference.