# Why is encourageable not a word?

Tags: grammaticality

What are general rules of thumb for creating adjectives with -able? I wanted to denote an object as having an ability to be encouraged, but "encourageable" and "encouragable" both are yielded as incorrect words by spell check and standard English dictionary used by Mac OS X dictionary widget. Is "encourageable" or "encouragable" a correct word/form for denoting an object having an ability to be encouraged?

Comment: Maybe it _was_ a word, but everyone kept hearing _incorrigible_.

Comment: **encourageable** *adjective* (comparative: more encourageable; superlative: most encourageable) 1.Able to be encouraged; suggestible. 2.Misspelling of incorrigible. see Wiktionary [encourageable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encourageable)

Comment: Where Have All the Flowers Gone? - Page 62, Alice Gerard - 2010 -
_I think the school encouraged the people who were __encouragable__ but didn't particularly change anybody's path, if they were not already interested in learning._

Comment: For more general 'enabling' of an existing word there is some info here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10440/creating-words-with-able-suffix

Answer (score 2):

It may not be a very common word, but it is a word alright. See this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=encourageable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cencourageable%3B%2Cc0)

Like Little Eva posted, [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encourageable) actually lists this word.

Comment: But with very very limited examples. It is not in the OED whilst inflections such as *encouragement, encouraging,..* etc are. I would say 'The study of grammar *is something to be encouraged*'. I can't imagine anyone saying it was *encourageable*.

Comment: Many of the hits on the first page of that n-gram are discussions of the word itself (as in dictionaries), or cases of it being used in dialogue by speakers who are either non-native, or playing with their words.

Comment: I could imagine using it in a situation such as this: "He discovered that his students were not readily encourageable."